# Cannot load model using WinML

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-machine-learning

As WinML is still fairly new and ever changing, I was hoping to know if anyone else has come across this error when trying to load a ONNX file made via the Custom Vision Service Export.

Type Error: Type (map(string,tensor(float))) of output arg (loss) of node (ZipMap) does not match expected type (seq(map(string,tensor(float))))

using Windows.AI.MachineLearning;

Windows RS5 1809 (build 17763.1)
UWP SDK 17763

Testing code from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ai.machinelearning

```
                // Load and create the model
            var modelFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri($"ms-appx:///{_modelFileName}"));
            _model = await LearningModel.LoadFromStorageFileAsync(modelFile);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Same exact issue and error.  I'm seeing it with other ONNX models as well.  I suspect it is a versioning issue.  WinML only supports ONNX 1.2 and my guess is that these other models, including Custom Vision, are older versions of ONNX models.

Comment: UPDATE:  Cracked open CV ONNX file and it looks like it is 1.2.2 - but not 100% of that.  If it is, no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Windows build 17763 (RS5) requires ONNX version 1.2 when Windows.AI.MachineLearning.

The Azure Custom Vision service supports this today .

[Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/custom-vision-onnx-uwp/) is a post around a sample app that does this.

As a note, you need to make sure your output data type matches when you bind.   In c# this looks something like this:

```
 public sealed class ModelOutput
        {
            public TensorString ClassLabel = TensorString.Create(new long[] { 1, 1 });
            public IList<IDictionary<string, float>> Loss = new List<IDictionary<string, float>>();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I received info from a Microsoft associate that stated that the windows.ai.machinelearning api only supports ONNX 2.  He didn't supply a date to which we can expect the custom vision service to export version 2 files.